# Main Interface, Actual Tabs or Separate Entities

Tags: c#, wpf

I am looking at doing a program as a hobby and to help a friend with a printing problem they have.   The application is pretty simple, just taking in data and sending that data to a print job so my friend doesn't have to manage each thing individually.

My question is this:  I want to use a tabbed main interface (Like how Meego OS is)  The problem I have is this doesn't seem like it would be structured very well.  That is, Instead of having a separate file for event handlers for each tab, they would all be in one file, the file with the tab control.

I thought about doing something like how some websites are made, [home.html, contact.html] [[the home icon in home.html is differentiated between contact.html when at home, contact icon is differentiated between home when on contact.html]]  but I need to handle background tasks.

I know those tasks will be in a separate thread (well, at least that's what makes sense to me)  but I am still not sure which is the standard method to do this.

Sorry for a wall of text, let me know what needs added or changed.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a UserControl for each page and add them to the TabControl. The code for each page will be in each UserControl and thus a separate file.